# control panel cron job error in laravel project

Tags: laravel, cron, command, cpanel

I have a laravel project and i create a command to do something. My goal is run the command every minute, So I add the command to the schedule. If in the local server I run

> php artisan schedule:run
>   It´s works but just one time.

So I upload my project for server and create a Cron Job in the CPanel but I have the error

> PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Illuminate\Console\Command' not found

Command in the Cron Job

> /usr/bin/php /path-to-project/app/Console/Commands/Notification.php

I dont understand why i can run the command in the local server but i can´t run in the online server.

Can anyone help me?
thx

Comment: Did you install composer dependencies with `composer install` on your server? Or asked differently, is there a `vendor` directory on the server?

Comment: yes, i have a vendor directory on the server

Answer (score 0):

What does the Kernel look like?  It should at least look like this:

```
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule) {
$schedule->command('artisanCommandNameHere')->everyMinute(); 
}
```

Personally, I would also add `->withoutOverlapping()` at the end as well to prevent simultaneous executions.

These docs should help you:  https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/scheduling

**UPDATE:**
I just looked again and realized this issue is different than I thought, given the information provided is correct.  First off, why are you not letting the Laravel scheduler handle making the cron job?  The whole point of the command was to take out the unnecessary complexity of hand-crafting a cron job.  Using the above block for the schedule function, just running `php artisan schedule:run` on server up will make the job repeat as specified.

However, if you're dead set on creating the cron job yourself, you're missing the artisan portion of your command.  You need to add it between php and filename, like so:

```
usr/bin/php /path-to-project/artisan /path-to-project/app/Console/Commands/Notification.php
```

Artisan is its own Symfony based CLI, and the commands in Laravel are built to run through it, not to be run as basic php files.

Comment: i will try to add your suggestion

Comment: Can you show us what your directives look like in the 'Notification' command?

Comment: i dont understand, you want that a show my directory structure?

Comment: I just meant your 'use' statements, specifically in the Notification.php file.

Comment: @Nuno I just made an update to my answer, I think you are missing artisan in your cron job.